# "desversionar" pasta no GIT

Tags: git

Eu tinha um arquivo alterado na pasta vendor que estava no gitignore, ai deu uma mensagem e eu não a li :( e dei um git -f add . e forcei a adicionar o arquivo que estava no gitignore, assim ele adicionou todo a pasta vendor.

A pergunta é como eu retiro toda essa pasta novamente do versionamento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git rm -r --cached <diretório>
```

Esse comando não apaga a cópia local.

Comment: obrigado, deu certo.